# null Date assigned by SimpleDateFormat.parse()

Tags: java

I hate to post another SimpleDateFormat question but I cannot find my answer on Google or in other threads. My code is below and the comments indicate the issue.

```
// The dateString format is "Thu Jul 19 00:04:11 +0000 2012". I confirmed that there
// is no preceding or trailing white space.
public static GregorianCalendar stringToDate(String dateString) {

    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d H:mm:ss Z yyyy");

    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString, pos);


    // 'Unknown Source' error thrown by setTime() as date is ultimately null.
    calendar.setTime(date);

    return calendar;

}
```

I have confirmed my dateString parameter comes through correctly, my position object starts at 0 and I have reviewed the SimpleDateFormat numerous times against http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. It looks right to me but I still tested various permutations of 'd' and 'H'. The only thing I can think is that there is some nuance to using this that I am missing, or I am way off base.

This compiles (javac 1.6.0_33), but when run (java version "1.6.0_33") it will not process even the first dateString value passed to it. I am running Windows 7 64-bit, Japanese version.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing "H:mm:ss" for "HH:mm:ss"

Comment: That was one permutation that I tried, but it doesn't work either (recompiled twice just to be sure).

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what your code looks like? You don't have any try/catch blocks? I don't think `parse` will ever return null - if it fails to parse, it'll throw an exception.

Comment: Word-for-word, yes. It returns 'java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Unknown Source)' and when I check date it is null.

Comment: @JonSkeet From javadoc: parse returns a Date parsed from the string. In case of error, returns null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the current locale on your computer is Japanese (which is very likely the case here), then `SimpleDateFormat` will just take the default locale (Japanese) and try to parse the date with it.

If the date string is always in English, you should specify `Locale.US` in the [`SimpleDateFormat` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29).

Comment: Thanks so much. I added a line 'Locale locale = new Locale("US");' and dropped the 'locale' variable into my SimpleDateFormat constructor. That worked! It displays 'EDT' rather than the RFC822 code that I want but I can sort that later.